# Is it possible to make this code use await/async rather than promises?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have this existing function, which works fine:

```js
const fetchWrapper = (resource, init) => {
  console.log('About to fetch...', resource)
  const p = fetch(resource, init)

  p.then(
    (response) => {
      console.log('The response is:', response)
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log('The error is:', error)
    }  
  )
  return p
}
```

I try to use async/await whenever possible. However, I am thinking that it's not actually *possible* to do so.
The main issue is that I want to return the promise returned by `fetch()`, so that the calling function can `await` as it would normally do.

But I also want *extra* things to happen just before calling `fetch()` (that's the easy part) and then straight after a network response.

To do that, I am attaching two callback (response and error) to the promise returned by `fetch()`.

If I were *not* to use promises, I would have to `await` for the `fetch()` call -- but then the caller won't receive the response till the promise is resolved, which is not what I want.

So... is it even possible to convert this code to full async/await?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below, which uses async and await, does the same thing as your code:

```js
// A simple promise response
const mockFetch = async (resource, init) => 'Response'

const fetchWrapper = async (resource, init) => {
    console.log('About to fetch...', resource)

    // You'll replace 'mockFetch' with 'fetch'
    const p = mockFetch(resource, init);

    // You can use a named function instead
    (async () => {
        try {
            const response = await p
            console.log('The response is:', response)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('The error is:', error)
        }
    })()

    return p
}

(async () => {
    const response = await fetchWrapper('', {})
    console.log(response)
})()
```

`mockFetch` is for demonstration purpose, you'll need to remove and replace `const p = mockFetch(resource, init);` with `const p = fetch(resource, init);`

Comment: Of course. What was I thinking? Oh my...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```js
const fetchWrapper = async (resource, init) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(resource, init);
    console.log('The response is:', response);
    return { success: true, response };
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('The error is:', error);
    return { success: false, error };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function fetchPost() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}});

  const post = await response.json();

  console.log(post)

  return post;
}

fetchPost() // Returning a Promise with the post
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getData = async () => {
   try{
     const fetchData = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
   if (fetchData.ok == true) {
     const respons = await response.json();
     return respons;
   } else {
    throw new Error("error")
   }

 } catch (err) {
     console.log(err)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ommiting usage of `.then()` / `.catch()` you could go with this:

```js
const fetchWrapper = (resource, init) => {

    // do stuff before fetch here ^^ 
    // ...

    // call the fetch
    const p = fetch(resource, init)

    const afterFetchEffects = async () => {

        // since it is "detached" (i call it like so..) 
        // you should ofc use try/catch
        try {

            // wait for the fetch() to finish
            await p

            // do some stuff after fetch
            // ... 
    
        } catch(err) {
            console.error('Error in detached after fetch promise..', err)
        }
    }

    // execute the wrapper which executes something after the fetch..
    // do not await it then it will do its own business.
    afterFetchEffects()

    // pass fetch immediatly back
    return p

}
```

I am not sure which approach is more readable^^